# Reflection call method - Argument Exception

Tags: c#

I've a `Dictionary<string, object>` for my commands. All commands has a class what extends from Cmd class. Now I try to call the `OnExecute` method, but I get an `ArgumentException`.

This is my function to call the method:

```
public void Execute(string command, string[] args)
    {
        try {
            Type type = commands[command].GetType();
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("OnExecute");
            method.Invoke(commands[command], args);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Program.Exception(ex);
        } catch (TargetException ex)
        {
            Program.Exception(ex);
        }
    }
```

And this is my Cmd class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Valda.Valda.Command
{
    public class Cmd
    {

        public Cmd()
        {

        }

        public void OnExecute(string[] args)
        {
            Program.WriteLine(args.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something like new object[] {args} as the second parameter to Invoke. It expects an array representing the params. You want the first param to be an array.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: @dman2306 its work! and 23.06 is my date with my girlfriend:D

Comment: @CanSpielt Glad I could help. I put it as a comment because I was on my cell phone.  I just posted it as an answer as well so hopefully it can help others too!

Answer (score 2):

Since your method takes one parameter (`OnExecute(string[] args)`) that is array of strings you need to pass array with single element of type `string[]` to [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
 method.Invoke(commands[command], new object[] {args});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass parameter as `object[]` type.

So, you must pass parameter like this:
`method.Invoke(commands[command], new object[] {args});`

not like this:
`method.Invoke(commands[command], args);`

`MethodBase.Invoke` method requires an parameter as object array(object[]) so you must make an object array and store all your parameters into array.

Answer (score 1):

The Invoke method takes two parameters, the Instance that has the method to invoke and an array representing the parameters. In your case, your first parameter is an array. As a result, what you're sending to the method is each member of your string array as an individual parameter rather than the array as the first parameter. What you want is:

`new object[] {args}`

This will make your `args` the first parameter to the `OnExecute` method.

Comment: Half right.  First parameter in the code given is an INSTANCE of the class to invoke the method on, not a MethodInfo

Comment: @roger willcocks you're right. I fixed it. Thanks for the correction